# Show that area are equals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$AIKJ$ is a square and $\mathrm{area}(AIKJ) = \mathrm{area}(\Delta BCA)$.

How can I prove $\triangle BMI +\triangle NCJ = \triangle MKN $ in area. I know its true because I draw it with Euclid's theorems but I just left to prove that any hint?[image]

Comment: Could you provide us more details about this image? For example, is $AIKJ$ a square?

Comment: Yes AIKJ is a square and area(AIKJ) = area($\triangle BCA)$

Comment: Isn't that condition enough to prove it?

Comment: But I have to justify why the sum of $\triangle BMI +\triangle NCJ = \triangle MKN$

Comment: I have to draw a square such that area of square are equal to a triangle but now I have to justify why $\triangle BMI +\triangle NCJ = \triangle MKN$

Comment: How you get the construction? What are the radiuses? How you decide of the centers... you need to provide ALL details. What you provided allow for uncertainty.

Comment: But what is there to prove? I am lost. If the bigger triangle area is same as the square area, then this has to be true.

Comment: Pentagon AIMNJ is common in both the triangle and the square. So taking that out from both sides, you get what you want.

Comment: If the square and the large triangle are equal than you subtract the common area and left with the proof you seek.

Comment: Simple arithmetic is all you need. As @MathLover says: Square AIKJ = pentagon AIMNJ + triangle KNM. Triangle ABC = pentagon AIMNJ + triangles BMI + CJN. What do you know about the areas of AIKJ and ABC?